# How to toggle two span texts with pure Javascript, No jQuery please

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying two toggle to spans text, but it does not switch or bring back  from display none to display block.

```js
function tog() {
  let fc = document.getElementById("fcol");
  let fe = document.getElementById("ferr");
  let pr = document.getElementById("pr");
  
  cdisp = fc.style.display;
  erdisp = fe.style.display;
  
  if (erdisp !== "block") {
    cdisp = "none";
    erdisp = "block";   
    pr.innerHTML = fe.textContent;
  } else {
    erdisp = "none";                                                                                                            
    cdisp = "block";
    pr.innerHTML = fc.textContent;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<span id = "fcol"  style="display: block; font-size:24px; color: green;">Only letters please</span> 
<span id="ferr"  style="display: none; font-size:24px; color: red;">Only letters please 2</span>
<button onClick="tog()">Sub</button>

<div id="pr"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are facing in your code is that you are updating the values of the cdisp and erdisp variables but not reflecting these changes back to the styles of the respective elements.

You can update your code by assigning the updated values to the style.display properties of the respective elements. Here's the updated code:

```
function tog() {
    let fc = document.getElementById("fcol");
    let fe = document.getElementById("ferr");
    let pr = document.getElementById("pr");
        
    if (fe.style.display === "none") {
        fc.style.display = "none";
        fe.style.display = "block";   
        pr.innerHTML = fe.textContent;
    } else {
        fe.style.display = "none";                                                                                                            
        fc.style.display = "block";
        pr.innerHTML = fc.textContent;
    }
}
```

In this version, the if statement checks if the ferr element is hidden (none), and if so, it sets its display to block, and sets the fcol element to none. The text content is then updated in the pr element accordingly. The else statement does the opposite, setting fcol to block and ferr to none.

```js
function tog() {
let fc = document.getElementById("fcol");
let fe = document.getElementById("ferr");
let pr = document.getElementById("pr");
    
if (fe.style.display === "none") {
    fc.style.display = "none";
    fe.style.display = "block";   
    pr.innerHTML = fe.textContent;
} else {
    fe.style.display = "none";                                                                                                            
    fc.style.display = "block";
    pr.innerHTML = fc.textContent;
}
}
```

```css
body {
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 150px;
        }
```

```html
I am trying to toggle to spans text, but it does not switch or bring back the from display none to display block.

<span id = "fcol"  style="display: block; font-size:24px; color:green;"> Only letters please </span> 
    <span id="ferr"  style="display: none; font-size:24px; color:red;" > Only letters please 2 </span>
    <button onClick="tog()">Sub</button>
    
    <div id="pr"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You should create a class that you can toggle. This simplifies the logic greatly.

```js
const
  fc = document.getElementById("fcol"),
  fe = document.getElementById("ferr"),
  pr = document.getElementById("pr");

function tog() {
  if (fe.classList.contains('hidden')) {
    pr.textContent = fe.textContent;
  } else {
    pr.textContent = fc.textContent;
  }
  
  // Toggle the classes
  fc.classList.toggle('hidden');
  fe.classList.toggle('hidden');
}

pr.textContent = fe.textContent; // Set initial text
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none; /* hide element */
}
```

```html
<!-- Make fcol hidden via the class -->
<span id="fcol" class="hidden" style="font-size:24px; color:green;"> Only letters please </span>
<span id="ferr" style="font-size:24px; color:red;"> Only letters please 2</span>
<button onClick="tog()">Sub</button>
<div id="pr"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just another way of speaking to this issue .. You are assigning the `string` of "block" and "none" to variables `cdisp` and `erdisp`.  You are not assigning the entire DOM object, so you are simply changing the variable, not the state or style of the object.  You still need to call on the DOM object itself.

So rather than show you *another* way to do it, this should help you understand *why* your code didn't work in the first place:

```
    if (erdisp !== "block") {
        fc.style.display = "none";
        fe.style.display = "block";   
        pr.innerHTML = fe.textContent;
    } else {
        fe.style.display = "none";
        fc.style.display = "block";
        pr.innerHTML = fc.textContent;
    }
```